# BTRFS qgroups warning/error

Tags: btrfs

when I shutdown my computer I will always receive an BTRFS error. Any idea how I can get rid of it? What does this error mean in detail? The computer is running fine in general.

System is Manjaro with full disk encryption and (obviously) BTRFS. I am using Timeshift for snapshot creation.

```
BTRFS warning (device dm-0): qgroup 0/256 has unreleased space, type 0 rsv 16384
BTRFS error (device dm-0): qgroup reserved space leaked
```

Some output that might help. Is other information needed?

```
# btrfs qgroup show /
qgroupid         rfer         excl 
--------         ----         ---- 
0/5          92.00KiB     92.00KiB 
0/256        13.96GiB     10.17MiB 
0/257       104.83GiB     36.40MiB 
...

# btrfs subvol list /
ID 256 gen 30193 top level 5 path @
...

# btrfs subvol show /
@
        Name:                   @
        UUID:                   dsdasd0909-r5s6-5646-5k7l-8388dadsadcea
        Parent UUID:            -
        Received UUID:          -
        Creation time:          2020-12-28 12:33:17 +0100
        Subvolume ID:           256
        Generation:             30193
        Gen at creation:        6
        Parent ID:              5
        Top level ID:           5
        Flags:                  -
        Snapshot(s):
...
        Quota group:            0/256
          Limit referenced:     -
          Limit exclusive:      -
          Usage referenced:     13.96GiB
          Usage exclusive:      10.17MiB
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had this issue after I restored my system to a previous snapshot.
If I remember correctly I got rid of this warning by:

- disabling btrfs quota support with '#btrfs quota disable /path/to/subvolume'
- listed quota groups '#btrfs qgroup show /path/to/subvolume' and deleted all of them with '#btrfs qgroup delete group-id'
- re-enabled quota support with '#btrfs quota enable /path/to/subvolume'

The path in my case was /

'After deleting a subvolume, you must manually delete the associated qgroup.' - https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Quota_support

I believe it may be related. If you restored your system to a snapshot and deleted the old one, you may solve this by just deleting the associated qgroup.

Comment: When I disable qgroups, I am not able to list them anymore.  
```
# btrfs qgroup show /  
ERROR: can't list qgroups: quotas not enabled  
```